# How to read and write images and video with PHP?

Tags: php, image, video

I am creating a downloadable zip file. In that zip, I want to add php, html, and images and videos.

All of them are in other folders.

I can read and write PHP and HTML files from other files/folders.

But I don't know how to read and write (or move from one folder to anther folder) images and videos.

Comment: what is purpose of such a zip file? is it for the other developers or for the end-user? If last - how do they supposed to run php files? anyway, there is no difference in reading and copying any type of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
function move_files($dir)
{
  if(is_dir($dir))
  {
    if($handle = opendir($dir))
    {
      while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false)
      {
        if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "Thumbs.db"/*pesky windows, images..*/)
        {
          $sourcefile = $dir.$file;
          $destinationfile = 'Your New Location';
          if (!copy($sourcefile, $destinationfile)) {
              echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
          }
        }
      }
      closedir($handle);
    }
  }
}

move_files("folder/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want to move files, see PHP manual: [copy](http://pl.php.net/copy), [unlink](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)